# Не загружаются картинки в базу данных на Denwer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, denwer

Пишу сайт на php. Сайт установлен на Денвере. К сайту привязана база данных Mysql. База данных называется sibir1, в базе данных имеется таблица sib1. Нужно с помощью запроса mysql загрузить картинку в базу данных. Прошу помочь разобраться в чем ошибка. Картинка не грузится совсем и ошибок не выдает программа никаких. С базой соединие происходит.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="img" type="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>


<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","sibir1","sibir1");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("sibir1", $con);

$img = $_POST['img'];

$bb=mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'sib1' ('id', 'img') VALUES (NULL, '$img')");
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибок не выдает, но и картинки в базе не появляются, когда смотришь phpMyAadmin (на скриншоте по идее в таблице должна появиться строка 8, а ее нет).

Comment: У Вас для id поля скорее всего стоит автоинкримент, а вы пытаетесь записать значение NULL. Попробуйте убрать с запроса id.

Comment: Без id тоже не вставляется. Это пробовала.